Can't Install Joomla on MAC. MAMP MySQL update issue
I am not a dev, but please help me. Searched everywhere can't find any solution.
Using Mac, trying to install Joomla, installed MAMP (free version). When trying to install joomla the following error appears: You need MySQL 8.0.13 or higher to continue the installation. Your version is: 5.7.39
Tried to install a newer version of MySQL however MAMP still shows the 5.7.39 version of MySQL.
Please help me to complete the installation.
